# button_click upon pressing Return in TextBox - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabindex, buttonclick

I've got an ASP WebForm with 2 Textboxes and 3 Buttons and I want a specific button_click event to be fired whenever I press return whilst in a TextBox - how would I achieve this?

I tried using the TabIndex-Property, unfortunately that actually only seems to work for tabbing, not for pressing return in a TextBox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey everyone, thanks for your answers - I just found the solution, for an aspx-page within a MasterPage I need to set

```
Form.DefaultButton = myButton.UniqueID;
```

instead of

```
Form.DefaultButton = myButton.ID;
```

which throws an error.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Set the form's AcceptButton to the button you want pressed:

```
form1.AcceptButton = btnOK;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately my ASP-Form is within a MasterPage and setting the DefaultButton on the MasterPages Form will result in getting an error on every other page.

Answer (score 2):

You can set which button is to be used as the default directly in mark-up of controls, by settings the `defaultbutton` property value to the `ID` of the desired button control, try this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="DefaultButtonId">
    <!-- content -->
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my aspx-file is within a MasterPage-File, setting the defaultbutton there results in an error on any other page, and programmatically setting it on my aspx-forms page_load also results in one.